# Qual a diferença entre long polling e o normal ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Estou tentando entender mais sobre long polling para "manipular" um site em tempo real, vi alguns videos e estou pensando até agora:

**Digamos que eu tenha uma data velha que esta no sql e eu faço um echo nela.**

Como o long polling irá saber se a velha data não será a mesma que ele vai buscar de tempo em tempo de acordo com a função setInterval...?

Digamos que eu queira exibir publicação de um blog em que todo o texto esteja no mysql, mas de repende eu publique uma nova publicação, e quem estiver na pagina na hora, irá ver a publicação na hora ( ava ), então como um código de long polling ira saber a diferença entre a velha publicação e a nova? Ate mesmo para nao dar conflito ou repetir a mesma data gravada no sql.

**Lembrando que não sei nada sobre long polling, então posso estar perguntando baboseiras...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar long-polling nesse contexto específico, o ideal é a página que faz o long polling receber um parametro que corresponde ao último timestamp que o utilizador tem.

Com isso, a página vai fazendo um query à base de dados para verificar se existem posts mais recentes, e caso existam, devolve a informação.

Do lado do cliente / browser, quando se recebe informação da página de long polling, refresca-se o conteudo do html com a nova informação recebida, e volta-se a chamar a página de long polling com o timestamp da informação que se acabou de receber.

Espero que o texto não seja confuso :)

A diferença é que em vez de estares sempre a fazer pedidos ajax do lado do cliente para saber se há posts novos, fazes um de x em x segundos ou minutos, e depois o pedido fica do lado do servidor a verificar se existem posts novos, e retorna resultados caso apareçam.

Comment: estou a começar a entender, mas dai o dono do site ira ter que especificar os parametros todo dia?

Comment: @Kevinmtk não percebi a pergunta...

Comment: Como vou fazer para nao repetir os posts

Comment: @Kevinmtk se precisa de ajuda convém no mínimo tentar ser mais explicito. Repetir os posts como? Quando? Em que situação? Quais posts? Porque motivo é que estão repetidos e onde?

Comment: Nao preciso de ajuda, preciso aprender sobre long polling > PHP > puxando mysql > index.php, existe uma data que ja esta no mysql com echo $row[…], e se long polling puxar as mesmas datas velhas que ja estão no mysql como citado a pouco neste comentário?

Comment: Como irei fazer com que busque pela data com ultimo timestamp inserido no ultimo id do mysql

Comment: @Kevinmtk Como tinha dito na minha resposta, depois de serem recebidas as informações dos posts mais recentes (através de Javascript por exemplo), volta-se a chamar a pagina que devolve os resultados, com um parametro que deve ser o ID ou a data do ultimo post obtido, evitando assim receber novamente informação duplicada. PS: isto é um forum de perguntas e respostas, onde questões concretas são respondidas. Para aprender estuda-se a linguagem e procuram-se tutoriais sobre o assunto.

Comment: Entendi, P.S, eu n entendo lendo pq na net só tem exemplos de qual uma situação eu nunca passarei pela minha vida para estudar, por isto prefiro exemplos simples, foi assim que aprendi já o html, css, o basico de php, basico de js.